# installutil not setting logon account username and password

Tags: c#, windows, installutil

I'm trying to install a new windows service (command line), which succeeds, however for my testing purposes I need to set a specific account/user and password. I've read plenty of posts and articles arguing I should use:

```
installutil /user=domain\user /password=password /unattended c:\path\to\exe
```

which successfully installs my service however when I go into the services window the "Log On As" user is set to "Local System" instead of the username and password i provided, as if it's been ignored. Am I missing something or are these parameters not what they're intended for?

Comment: I think the proper flag is `/username` just for future reference

Answer (score 2):

Did you have added Installer(right clicking on design of service->Add Installer) for your service? Can you check the properties for ServiceProcessInstaller instance like below,
[image]

Check whether Account is set to user and if it is Local system just change it. And while you are installing using installutil you will be prompted for username/password. Use this for testing purpose and once you are deploying rechange the same.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not exactly what i was hoping for but it works for now thanks!

Comment: Can you let me know what we are supposed to do?

Comment: I need to script this and so I was hoping to be able to do without the prompt. Also putting in the username and password in the code is not an option so not sure if I'm dead in the water